# ActiveMQ Artemis official Docker image

Tags: docker, activemq-artemis

We are working on ActiveMQ Artemis and looking for an official Docker image to use in our project. I checked hub.docker.com and other areas but could not find it.

Does anyone have an idea if there is any and can be published in the near term?

Answer (score 3):

Did you look into https://artemiscloud.io/ ? Also iirc there is a docker file provided with Artemis distribution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use one of those images:
https://quay.io/repository/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-init?tab=tags

I'm not sure whether they are really usable or whether you can call them "official" images.

On the [Artemis website](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/), the manual creation of a Docker image is referenced. The Dockerfiles are maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/artemis-docker).
We build the image by ourself, because we add there some base configuration and migration scripts.

Comment: Maybe we can call these images official. They are just not hosted on dockerhub, but on Red Hat dockerhub equivalent which is quay.io.
There is an instruction on how to use activemq-artemis-broker image: https://artemiscloud.io/docs/tutorials/deploybasicimage/

Answer (score 2):

This one looks pretty official:  https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/activemq-artemis

Comment: This official images is quite recent. It appear first on 27 of July 2023.